# How to fix Assassins Creed from pinging dead servers/how to "reroute" the IP addresses of those servers?

Tags: technical-issues, networking, assassins-creed

Apparently the game pings these IP Addresses:

- 216.98.48.18
- 216.98.48.53
- 216.98.48.57
- 216.98.48.133
- 216.98.48.134

Is there a way to make the game think that these IP addresses are alive? such as when my pc tries to ping one of these IP addresses, it'll ping localhost instead?

I've tried to edit the hosts file, but I'll only get timeouts when attempting to ping the mentioned addresses. I've also unplugged my ethernet cable which seems to fix the crashing, but that's quite inconvenient.

Comment: Presumably it's not pinging these addresses just to see if they're there, but to gather some new 'information'. https://www.robtex.com/ip-lookup/216.98.48.18

Comment: Try to use the `hosts` file to map these addresses to a real IP, for example ubisoft.com at `3.213.190.175`.

Comment: https://steamcommunity.com/app/15100/discussions/0/864949037837351686/

Comment: @harrymc well i tried whats in the steam forum. it doesn't seem to work. afaik i can't map one ip to another in the hosts file. "The IP address should be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name".

Comment: What happens if you block the app from the network entirely using the built in windows firewall? If that doesn't work.. are you able to down the network, start the game, and restart the network?  You should be able to do this from a batch file.  Not ideal, but should work.